# Trouble initializing Lightbox plugin (Lightbox 2 with Jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, lightbox, lightbox2

hope someone can help me!

I have built the html5/bootstrap3 website [www.girlsfly2.ca](http://www.girlsfly2.ca) and am working on implementing 4 gallery pages documenting 4 years of event photos.  The photos are arranged using Desandro's Packery plugin (still a work in progress) and I would like to incorporate the Lightbox plugin so that visitors can click on a gallery photo, see a larger version of the thumbnail which will include a caption with photographer credit, and then be able to navigate forward or back to adjacent photos or close back to the gallery.

The first test page is located here:  http://www.girlsfly2.ca/past_events_PACKERY.html  Though I thought I followed the developer's  initialization instructions correctly, obviously I've made a mistake somewhere because nothing happens when you click on any of the pictures.

If someone could point out what I've missed I would be eternally grateful!  I'll likely have more questions as I refine/customize the options, but at the moment I'm at a standstill until I can get the plugin to work!

Thanks for any help and suggestions!

Kirsten

Comment: Your console from 2nd link says this -> **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) -http://www.girlsfly2.ca/css/lightbox.css** which means the lightbox css was not loaded properly or not at all present in the specified path and if I visit the above path and check the `css` its empty!! kindly make a note!!

Comment: Thanks @GuruprasadRao - I added the missing term Lightbox to the path for the Lightbox CSS inclusion and that solved the problem - THANK YOU!  Now to figure out how to customize the plugin!

Comment: Anytime. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Your console from 2nd link says this -> Failed to load resource: the
>   server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   -girlsfly2.ca/css/lightbox.css which means the lightbox css was not loaded properly or not at all present in the specified path and if I
>   visit the above path and check the css its empty!! kindly make a
>   note!! –  Guruprasad Rao

Thanks to Guruprasad Rao for pointing out the discrepency regarding the CSS!  I had included the Lightbox CSS in the HTML but the path for the file location was incorrect.  Problem solved!

Best Regards,
Kirsten